# What is this @_downgrade_exhaustivity_check Swift private keyword?

Tags: swift

While browsing the Swift repository I came across that keyword.

What does that mean?

For instance, from [Time.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Dispatch/Time.swift#L166):

```
public enum DispatchTimeInterval : Equatable {
    case seconds(Int)
    case milliseconds(Int)
    case microseconds(Int)
    case nanoseconds(Int)
    @_downgrade_exhaustivity_check
    case never
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should talk about this in a Github issue.

Comment: @dengApro Is not possible to create issues in Swift repository. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual commit message states

> **Implement @_downgrade_exhaustivity_check**
>
> Dispatch requests the ability to add a new case, but to treat missing
>   instances of that case in patterns as warnings instead of errors.  It
>   is still an error to make reference to the annotated case in at least
>   one pattern then not cover the rest of the space, but it is not an
>   error to omit the space of patterns referencing the case entirely.
>
> This attribute is private and uglified to intentionally discourage its
>   use outside just this one use case.

Source https://git.snooey.net/Mirrors/swift/commit/03527d9eec65324434011d23219e2bf7525642c6

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the idea is that if you have a switch on a DispatchTimeInterval and you omit the `never` case, you get a warning instead of a compile error.